# Finding the location of a program/file Python

Tags: python, windows, pywin32, win32gui

Here is my code to find the name of the active window. I now need to be able to find the location of the program.

```
 import win32gui
 window = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
 active_window_name = win32gui.GetWindowText(window)
 print(active_window_name)
```

How do i find the location of the program and file using either the name or anything else with out manually inputting the name.

Comment: Maybe not visible all !

Comment: `win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(window)` will return the thread and process IDs that own the window. For a console window, the owner is conhost.exe, but the API special cases this to return either the initial process that attached to the console or, if that process has already exited, the current foreground process in the console.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to find the location of the file as in the directory path. There's multiple ways to do this, and the easiest one looks like this:

```
import os 
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```